# Registros duplicados

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un sistema de Tickets, el código funciona un 90% considerando los requirimientos del sistema, el problema está en que a veces cuando hago un registro, éste me sale duplicado.

He probado varias cosas sin éxito, cabe aclarar que no puedo tener campos únicos en mi tabla de mi base de datos (a excepción de mi `PK`). El problema es que duplica todo, como si el script se ejecutara dos veces.

Anexo mis códigos para ver si me pueden orientar.

**Código donde llamo el Modal**:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> Tickets
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrarTicket" id="btnagregarTicket">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Ticket
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <div class="removeMessages"></div>
                                <table id="tickets" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No</th>
                                            <th>Actualizado</th>
                                            <th>Ref</th>
                                            <th>Categoria</th>
                                            <th>Requerimiento</th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th>Prioridad</th>
                                            <th>Creado</th>
                                            <th>Asignado</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>                                        
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Código HMTL:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registrarTicket" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-primary" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Crear Ticket</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="" method="post" id="frmregistrarTicket" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="messages"></div>                        

                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">¿Es hijo?</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="regEshijo" name="regEshijo">
                                            <option value="0">No</option>
                                            <option value="1">Si</option>
                                        </select>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Si el ticket a generar depende de otro ya creado">
                                          <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group" id="referencia"> 
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">ID Referencia</span>
                                        <input type="text" id="regReferencia" name="regReferencia" class="form-control" placeholder="Referencia ticket padre">
                                        <button type="button" id="heredar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Requerimiento</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regCategoria" id="regCategoria" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group" id="idSubcategoria_">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Subcategoria</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regSubcategoria" id="regSubcategoria" required>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Tema</span>
                                <input type="text" id="regTema" name="regTema" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo tema" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Descripción</span>
                                <textarea rows="3" id="regDescripcion" name="regDescripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Cliente</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regCliente" id="regCliente" required>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group" id="idSucursal_">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Sucursal</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regSucursal" id="regSucursal" required>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">                              
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Tipo de ticket</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regTipo" id="regTipo" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Servicio</option>
                                            <option value="2">Incidente</option>
                                            <option value="3">Problema</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Asignar a</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regTecnico" id="regTecnico" required>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Status</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regStatus" id="regStatus" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Abierto</option>
                                            <option value="2">Asignado</option>
                                            <option value="3">Pendiente</option>
                                            <option value="4">Cerrado</option>
                                            <option value="5">Cancelado</option>
                                            <option value="6">Resuelto</option>
                                            <option value="7">Reabierto</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Prioridad</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regPrioridad" id="regPrioridad" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Critica </option>
                                            <option value="2">Urgente </option>
                                            <option value="3">Alto </option>
                                            <option value="4">Medio </option>
                                            <option value="5">Bajo</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <label class="input-group-addon">Archivo(s)</label>
                        <input class="file-loading" id="imagen" type="file" multiple name="image[]">
                        <div id="errorBlock" class="help-block"></div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="limpiarCampos">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar_">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Código PHP:**

```
if($_POST) {
        $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        #Obtener el Usuario que inició sesion para saber quién está manipulando los tickets.
        $usuarioCreado = $_SESSION['u_usuario']['PK_idUsuario'];            
        $regEshijo = $_POST["regEshijo"];

        #Si el ticket no es hijo la REFERENCIA será 0, de caso contrario tomará el valor del campo referencia.
        $regReferencia = $_POST["regReferencia"];
        if (empty($regReferencia)) {
            $regReferencia = 0;
        }else{
            $regReferencia = $_POST["regReferencia"];
        }       

        #Datos del formulario.
        $regCategoria = $_POST["regCategoria"];
        $regSubcategoria = $_POST["regSubcategoria"];
        $regTitulo = $_POST["regTema"];
        $regDescripcion = $_POST["regDescripcion"];
        $regTipo = $_POST["regTipo"];
        $regTecnico = $_POST["regTecnico"];
        $regStatus = $_POST["regStatus"];
        $regPrioridad = $_POST["regPrioridad"];
        $regCliente = $_POST["regCliente"];         
        $regUbicacion = $_POST['regSucursal'];
        $regAlerta = 1;
        $regEscalado = 1;
        $alta = 'ALTA';
        $atencion = 'ATENCION';
        $cliente = 'CLIENTE';

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ticket (FK_idUbicacion, FK_idSubcategoria, tituloTicket, descripcionTicket, statusTicket, prioridadTicket, alertaTicket, escaladoTicket, tipoTicket, esHijo, refTicket) VALUES  ('$regUbicacion','$regSubcategoria','$regTitulo','$regDescripcion','$regStatus','$regPrioridad','$regAlerta', '$regEscalado', '$regTipo', '$regEshijo' , '$regReferencia')");
        $idTick = mysqli_insert_id($con);

        #Dar de alta en la tabla ticket_usuario los datos del Cliente, del Técnico y quien creó el Ticket.
        $query1 = mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO ticket_usuario(FK_idTicket, FK_idUsuario, status) VALUES ('$idTick', '$usuarioCreado', '$alta')");           
        $query2 = mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO ticket_usuario(FK_idTicket, FK_idUsuario, status) VALUES ('$idTick', '$regTecnico', '$atencion')");
        $query3 = mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO ticket_usuario(FK_idTicket, FK_idUsuario, status) VALUES ('$idTick', '$regCliente', '$cliente')");           

        #Crear las carpetas para los archivos, se agruparán por  CATEGORIA Y SUBCATEGORIA
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE PK_idCategoria ='".$regCategoria."'");
        $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $rutaCat = $cat['categoriaDesc'];
        #$des = str_replace(" ","_",$rutaCat);
        $des = sanear_string($rutaCat);
        #$nuevo = sanear_string($cadena);



        $sql1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE PK_idSubcategoria ='".$regSubcategoria."'");
        $subcat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1);
        $rutaSubcat = $subcat['subcategoriaDesc'];
        #$des1 = str_replace(" ","_",$rutaSubcat);          
        $des1 = sanear_string($rutaSubcat);

        #Ruta para los archivos
        $archivo = "../archivos/$des/$des1/";

        #Crear carpetas sino existen.
        if (!file_exists($archivo)) {
            mkdir($archivo, 0777, true);
        }

        #Cargar Imagenes
        if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
        #Numero de archivos a cargar
            $num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
            {
                #Ver si hay archivos para subir
                if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]))
                {
                    #echo "No se encontraron archivos";
                }
                else
                {
                    #Copiar imagenes a la carpeta correspondiente de acuerdo a la marca
                    if(@copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i],"$archivo".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i])){
                        $path = "".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                        $query3= mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO archivoticket(FK_idTicket, archivoTicket) VALUES('$idTick', '$path')");                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #echo "No se pudo subir el archivo";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #Si todos los datos se han insertado correctamente se muestra un mensaje de éxito, de caso contrario una alerta de error.           
        if($query === TRUE && $query1 === TRUE  && $query2 === TRUE && $query3 === TRUE) {
            $validator['success'] = true;
            $validator['messages'] = "Ticket creado correctamente";
        } else {
            $validator['success'] = false;
            $validator['messages'] = "Error al crear el ticket";
        }
        $con->close();
        echo json_encode($validator);
    }
```

**Código jQUERY:**

```
$("#btnagregarTicket").on('click', function() {     
    //$(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".messages").html("");
    $("#frmregistrarTicket")[0].reset();
    $("#frmregistrarTicket").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmregistrarTicket"));
        var ruta = "crudTickets.php?op=create";
        $.ajax({
            url: ruta,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(response)
            {
               if(response.success == true) {
                    $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                    '<strong> <span class="fa fa-check"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                    '</div>');

                    // Recargar la tabla y limpiar los campos
                    tblTicket.ajax.reload();
                    $("#frmregistrarTicket")[0].reset();
                    $("#registrarTicket").modal('hide');
                    location.reload();              

                    //Error 
                } else {
                    $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                    '<strong> <span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                    '</div>');
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Dónde tienes el botón '#btnagregarTicket' que llamas en JQuery?. Reviso el código HTML pero no lo veo.

Comment: Tengo en la misma vista donde ejecuto el modal. De echo este boton lo llamo asi: **<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrarTicket" id="btnagregarTicket">**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De seguro estás llamando el proceso AJAX dos veces al definir un evento `onClick` con un `onSubmit` dentro.

Prueba utilizar el siguiente código JQuery:

```
$("#btnagregarTicket").on('click', function(e) {     
    //$(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".messages").html("");
    $("#frmregistrarTicket")[0].reset();

    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmregistrarTicket"));
    var ruta = "crudTickets.php?op=create";

    $.ajax({
        url: ruta,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response.success == true) {
                $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                '<strong> <span class="fa fa-check"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                '</div>');

                // Recargar la tabla y limpiar los campos
                tblTicket.ajax.reload();
                $("#frmregistrarTicket")[0].reset();
                $("#registrarTicket").modal('hide');
                location.reload();              

                //Error 
            } else {
                $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                '<strong> <span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                '</div>');
            }
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, he probado el código (con algunas modificaciones) y hasta ahora me ha funcionado, al pendiente de confirmar lo contrario!!